# What is the powershell script for getting the 'Created By' of a Site Collection on SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, script

Can I check whether it is possible to run the powershell script to see 'Created By' of a Site Collection for SharePoint Online? I'm currently runnng this line (below) but the information that I want is not there.

```
Get-SPOSite -Identity <SiteCollectionURL> -Detailed | Select *
```

Thanks.

Comment: No, AFAIK it isn't a retrievable property with that commandlet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a limited support of PowerShell Commands available for SharePoint Online, We can use csom in PowerShell script to get the author of a site collection,  the lack of cmdlets for items at a lower scope than the Site Collection. Specifically, there is no `Get-SPOWeb` or `Get-SPOList` cmdlet or anything of the sort for SharePoint Online.

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

# replace these details (also consider using Get-Credential to enter password securely as script runs)..
$username = "xxx@xxx.onmicrosoft.com"
$password = "xxxxx"
$url = "https://xxx.sharepoint.com"

$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force

# the path here may need to change if you used e.g. C:\Lib..
Add-Type -Path "c:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "c:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"
# note that you might need some other references (depending on what your script does) for example:
Add-Type -Path "c:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Taxonomy.dll"

# connect/authenticate to SharePoint Online and get ClientContext object..
$clientContext = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($url)
$credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($username, $securePassword)
$clientContext.Credentials = $credentials

if (!$clientContext.ServerObjectIsNull.Value)
{
  Write-Host "Connected to SharePoint Online site: '$Url'" -ForegroundColor Green
  $rootWeb = $clientContext.Web
  $clientContext.Load($rootWeb)
  $clientContext.ExecuteQuery()

  Write-Host "Title " $rootWeb.Title
  Write-Host "Web Created by" $rootWeb.Author
}
```

[Source](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f7749385-cb02-4ec3-8e66-009aa9e9f9cb/sharepoint-online-management-shell-powershell-to-connect-spo-site-collection?forum=sharepointgeneral)

Comment: Thank you Karthik. But this is on SharePoint Online, the path may be hard to fill a path value.

Comment: @kodeist You can download and install the DLLs locally to talk to SPO, https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42038

Comment: @EricAlexander Oh yes, that's right. Thanks for the note.